# What are some of the common culprits that would inject a blank page?

Tags: memoir, blank-page

I have a document with a mostly empty header that just includes a bunch of chapters.

Each chapter consists of something like this - a \chapter heading and a bunch of text:

```
\chapter{Foo Bar}

A bunch of text - no math formulas, nothing fancy.
```

When the I typeset the document, a full blank page is injected between the first chapter and subsequent chapters - `first' and` second' but the chapters are all typeset as I expect. Each
chapter starts on a new page, but there are no blank pages.

This seems to the case even if I reorder the chapter. For example,
\include(second)
\include(first)
\include(third)
\include(forth)

Inserts a blank page between the `second' and 'first' - so I suspect that something has to be up with the main document.

What are some common culprits that could be causing this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}


\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}


\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}

\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}[Script=Hebrew]{Hadasim CLM}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfontsf}[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam CLM}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfonttt}[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}

\begin{document}

%\texthebrew{דוגמא לגופני ברירת מחדל}

\include{first}

\include{second}

\include{third}

\include{fourth}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should provide an example, but by default chapters start on right hand (odd) pages so will have a blank page if the previous chapter ended on an odd page.

Comment: Thanks David - I think that explains it.

Comment: To change this default behavior, you can use the option `openany`: `\documentclass[12pt,openany]{memior}`.